# How to get current and previous ids of current id in one query(mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is like this:

```
employee(empid, ename,job);
```

The current **empid** is for example 10, I want the previous and next empids from the database.

The next and previous values may not be 11 and 9 respectively, I need to get it from the database only in a single query.
Could any body please help me with this?

Comment: If nothing else ties them together, then make a subselect for each, where empid is larger than current in one and smaller in the other, and then you can use TOP 1 and order by in those sub selects. Not terrible effective, but doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ex. empid = 4

```
select * from employee
where empid = (select max(empid) from employee where empid < 4)
   OR empid = (select min(empid) from employee where empid > 4)
```

Comment: You are awesome...! I have been fiddling with this for the past 1 hour, you saved my time..! Thanks